# Conditional ARG in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, conditional-statements

I have a Dockerfile and I want to do different things based on a build argument to determine isDev or not.

In the Dockerfile, I have:

```
ARG isDev
RUN echo "what is in isDev ? $isDev"
RUN if ["${isDev}" = "1"] ; 
     then ..... do dev stuff .... ; 
     else .... do production stuff ; 
    fi
```

I am building with my --build-arg isDev=1

```
Step 14/25 : ARG isDev
 ---> Running in 0a3de5fea466
Removing intermediate container 0a3de5fea466
 ---> a6d79a08a97e
Step 15/25 : RUN echo "what is in isDev ? $isDev"
 ---> Running in 92235e8b0c6a
what is in isDev ? 1
Removing intermediate container 92235e8b0c6a
 ---> a7b064687480
Step 16/25 : RUN if ["${isDev}" = "1"] ; then ... do dev stuff ... ; else  ... do production stuff ... ; fi
 ---> Running in bbe6a047705a
[91m/bin/sh: 1: [1: not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to like this answer, you're missing a space after `[`. You'll need another space before the closing bracket, and you need to escape the linefeeds. At least that's what I'm seeing at first glance.

```
ARG isDev
RUN echo "what is in isDev ? $isDev"
RUN if [ "${isDev}" = "1" ] ; \
     then ..... do dev stuff .... ; \
     else .... do production stuff ; \
    fi
```

Comment: wow one of those errors!  Thank you cant believe I missed the spaces! Thank you

Comment: @user4447899 figured you wouldn't like it, made my own share of face palms. Fun tip for the day, `[` is actually a binary on linux systems, likely in `/usr/bin/[`. So `[1` means linux cannot find that binary.

Comment: Often fresh pair of eyes is all you need. Thanks for the help and unblocking me. Regards

Comment: I've been looking for this for at least an hour. Guess we all have those days